# Android Could not play mp4 video with VideoView?

Tags: android, video, mp4, codec

I am trying to stream mp4 video with fullscreen activity only contain of videoview. But even though it easily play on my galaxt s3, it does not play most of the devices. I suspect its about encoding of the video (by the way you have to be codec guru to know which video play which not).

Here is the code I am using.

```
    //make screen full with video
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_video);

    //get extra video source string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null){
        videoSrc = intent.getStringExtra(TefalTvApp.RECIPE_VIDEO_SOURCE);
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Recipe title : " + videoSrc);   
        }
    }

    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.recipeVideo);
    controller = new MediaController(FullScreenVideoActivity.this);
    controller.setMediaPlayer(video);
    video.setMediaController(controller);
    video.setVideoPath(videoSrc);
    video.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Hello wworld");
            }
        }
    });

    video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            video.requestFocus();
            video.start();  
        }
    });
```

Here is the debug result. You have the video url in the debug.

```
08-23 23:25:53.349: D/RecipeDetailActivity(18179): Video src : http://www.tefaltv.com/Upload/Video/acticook_kiymalifasulye.mp4
08-23 23:25:53.379: I/ApplicationPackageManager(18179): cscCountry is not German : TUR
08-23 23:25:53.389: D/FullScreenVideoActivity(18179): Recipe title : http://www.tefaltv.com/Upload/Video/acticook_kiymalifasulye.mp4
08-23 23:25:53.399: D/VideoView(18179): onMeasure()
08-23 23:25:53.399: I/VideoView(18179):     Setting size: 480x295
08-23 23:25:53.439: I/MediaPlayer(18179): uri is:http://www.tefaltv.com/Upload/Video/acticook_kiymalifasulye.mp4
08-23 23:25:53.439: I/MediaPlayer(18179): path is null
08-23 23:25:53.439: D/MediaPlayer(18179): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
08-23 23:25:53.519: D/VideoView(18179): onMeasure()
08-23 23:25:53.519: I/VideoView(18179):     Setting size: 480x295
08-23 23:25:57.689: I/VideoView(18179): start()
08-23 23:25:57.739: D/VideoView(18179): onMeasure()
08-23 23:25:57.739: I/VideoView(18179):     Setting size: 480x270
08-23 23:25:57.759: E/MediaPlayer(18179): error (1, -2147483648)
08-23 23:25:57.769: I/VideoView(18179): start()
08-23 23:25:57.779: E/MediaPlayer(18179): start called in state 0
08-23 23:25:57.779: E/MediaPlayer(18179): error (-38, 0)
08-23 23:25:57.799: E/MediaPlayer(18179): Error (1,-2147483648)
08-23 23:25:57.799: D/VideoView(18179): Error: 1,-2147483648
08-23 23:25:57.799: E/MediaPlayer(18179): Error (-38,0)
08-23 23:25:57.799: D/VideoView(18179): Error: -38,0
```

UPDATE :
Video encoding details :
Format : H.264, 624 x 351
AAC, 44100 Hz, Stereo (L R)
FPS : 25
Data Rate: 2.23mbit/s
Current size : 624x351 px actual

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly because of the encoding . I see that your video file resolution is 624x351 which is not standard, so that might be one reason . Also check the maximum bit rate and fps as all the mobile devices have some cap over it , like for most of android mobile phones its 30fps. You should refer this document to make your file compatible with all the android phones. [Android Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Also, if you can share the encoding command (if you are executing one), it will be easy to trace the issue.

Comment: no I am not the one providing the video. But I can check video encoding details on quick time and update the question.

Comment: Yeah, I did check your encoding details :- Dimension :- 624X351, Codecs :AAC, H.264 , Audio channel -2 , and bit rate 2,233. I can help you out in testing standard videos . This page we made to chose standard for our own application. Let me know if it is helpful.  Where HLS is Http live streaming (m3u8 playlist format), and rest Mp4. http://ec2-23-20-128-151.compute-1.amazonaws.com/test.html . We made it for iPhones , but you can draw some conclusions for android too.

Comment: yeah I posted encoding details same as you. Let me check the one you provide.

Comment: great, let me know which one is working for you , so that I can provide you the encoding details.

Comment: ok I just tested your mp4 version but it gives the same error. Here is the url that I used from your page. http://ec2-23-20-128-151.compute-1.amazonaws.com/tests/videos/480x320.mp4

Comment: Here is the debug error 08-24 00:37:06.399: E/MediaPlayer(18527): error (1, -2147483648)
08-24 00:37:06.439: I/VideoView(18527): start()
08-24 00:37:06.439: E/MediaPlayer(18527): start called in state 0
08-24 00:37:06.439: E/MediaPlayer(18527): error (-38, 0)
08-24 00:37:06.459: E/MediaPlayer(18527): Error (1,-2147483648)
08-24 00:37:06.459: D/VideoView(18527): Error: 1,-2147483648
08-24 00:37:06.459: E/MediaPlayer(18527): Error (-38,0)
08-24 00:37:06.459: D/VideoView(18527): Error: -38,0

Comment: did you try running from test.html. From what I believe, last video in test.html should work and also if the bit rate is more then 2mbps ( like in your original case), it might be problematic. Try with low quality videos , and html5 video tag.  Can you tell me which android versions you are testing on?

Comment: I hardcoded every video url you just gave me inside my app with. But none of them worked on my Galaxy Ace 2.3.3 I should also test them on my galaxy s3 too to see if its device specific. But all got not "can not play video" I do not suspect from my code cause it seems obvious way to do it.

Comment: Do not hardcode it . Run my test.html URL in your browser. and then test.

Comment: Ok only mpeg ones seems to be playing on browser (including last one). Also I did test videos on my galaxt s3 and each one can smoothly played.

Comment: great, HLS videos are specifically for iphone/ipad, so they won't work on browsers other than safari. Anyways, so you should be able to fix the issues just by opting right encoding format. good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you for the following Code wherein i am running my application successfully

The Code is as Follows:

XML file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f0f0f0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnVideoGallery"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/gallery" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnVideoGallery"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/below_this_text_video_will_be_displayed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vvDisplayVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java File:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnVideoGallery,btnCancel;
    private VideoView vvDisplayVideo;
    /** The Constant PICK_VIDEO. */
    private static final int PICK_VIDEO=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_options);

        btnVideoGallery=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVideoGallery);
        vvDisplayVideo=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vvDisplayVideo);
        btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        vvDisplayVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnVideoGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent video=new Intent();
                video.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                video.setType("video/*");
                startActivityForResult(video, PICK_VIDEO);

            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent goStartUp=new Intent(VideoActivity.this, StartUpActivity.class);
                goStartUp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(goStartUp);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_VIDEO) {

            vvDisplayVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vvDisplayVideo.setVideoURI(data.getData());
            vvDisplayVideo.setFocusable(true);
            MediaController mc=new MediaController(this);
            vvDisplayVideo.setMediaController(mc);
            Log.i("True", "Executed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent goStartUp=new Intent(VideoActivity.this, StartUpActivity.class);
        goStartUp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(goStartUp);
        finish();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Also you can modify the Manifest File as per your use:

```
<manifest ...
<uses-sdk...  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

<application .....
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your video size which is being streamed is different from your videoview size