# android get path of recorded video/audio

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I let the user record a video/audio by doing following:

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(videoIntent, VIDEO_REQUEST);
         //pretty the same thing for audio
```

I'm not sure what to do in the onActivityResult() method to get the Uri of the recorded file and then convert it to an absolute path like /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1231.avi

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my program wherein you will get how to get the Path.The Link is as follows:-[Imp Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099579/android-could-not-play-mp4-video-with-videoview/13456942#13456942).